# Rails simple_form - is it possible to display radio_buttons with just button labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

This code:

```
<%= f.input :exploratory, as: :radio_buttons,
  collection: [['Exploratory', true], ['Preparatory', false]],
  label: false %>
```

Produces this result:

[image]

Which is almost exactly what I want - the only problem is the "Exploratory" label above the radio buttons.

Is there a way to have simple_form omit the label for the radio button set and just display the individual button labels? Or if that is not possible, is there a way that I can set the label to a different value.

I'm using Simple Form 4.1.0 with Rails 5.2.3 and Bootstrap 4.3.1.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with the `simple_form_bootstrap` wrappers, for collection inputs you have to specify `legend_tag: false` instead of `label: false`.

Comment: YES YES YES! 100% what I was looking for. Thank you Roy!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `label: false`

```
<%= f.input :exploratory, as: :radio_buttons,
    collection: [['Exploratory', true], ['Preparatory', false]],
    label: false %>
```

This should generate the HTML without label

**Tested**

[image]

Also, you can change the label by adding `label: 'Changed label'`

```
<%= f.input :exploratory, as: :radio_buttons,
    collection: [['Exploratory', true], ['Preparatory', false]],
    label: 'Changed Label' %>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a difference - but thank you for showing me how to get rid of the ```label_method: :second, value_method: :first``` part.

Comment: It does remove the label as expected.

Comment: The label "Exploratory" (the name of the boolean field that gets the result of the radio buttons) is displayed above the radio buttons as an overall label for both buttons.

Comment: Setting the label to a new value does work ```label: 'Changed Label'``` as does setting the label to an empty string.

Comment: label: false doesn't work for me - it's still there

Comment: you can use `label_text: false`